# PhantomJS why does webpage.onConsoleMessage does not catch <script> in the html opened

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

For the sake of convenience, in this question, I defined the `contents` const to be my HTML file.

```js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

const contents = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         console.log("TEXT WITHIN HTML");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
`;

page.open(contents, function(status) {
    console.log('Status: ' + status);
    page.evaluate("function() { console.log('page.evaluated stuff')}");
});

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};
```

When running `$ phantomjs test.js`:

```sh
$ phantomjs test.js 
Status: success
CONSOLE: page.evaluated stuff (from line # in "")
```

It successfully catches `console.log` that I `page.evaluate`, but not the one in the `<scripts>` section of the HTML file.

Why is that? I'm not very familiar with Phantomjs.

Answer (score 0):

Phantomjs does not support ES6.

I tested your code for errors.

I don't know how you got the result.
Try this.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var contents = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head> <script type="text/javascript"> console.log("TEXT WITHIN HTML\\n");</script> </head> <body></body> </html>';

page.open("about:blank", function(status) {
    page.content = contents;
    console.log('Status: ' + status);
    page.evaluate(function () {
        (function() { console.log('page.evaluated stuff')})()
    });
});

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};
```